# Loading images from different URLs on the same ImageView and animating them in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation, android-volley

I have to load different images in the same ImageView and animate them.
Current I am using images from my drawable folder aand animating them using [AnimationDrawable](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/drawable-animation.html). But i dont know how to animate loaded images from the URLs. I am using [Volley](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html) to load the images.

```
if(photoUrl!=null){
        imageLoader.get(photoUrl, new ImageLoader.ImageListener() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(ImageLoader.ImageContainer response, boolean isImmediate) {
                holder.venueImage.setImageBitmap(response.getBitmap());
            }

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            }
        });
    }
```

[image: first image]
[image: fading into second]

Comment: Edit your question with the animation and Volley code.

Comment: @iturki what can i do to load the images in the same imageView ?

Comment: @iturki i am using imageLoader to load the image. i dont know how to load an array of images urls to the same imageView

Comment: Could you explain what are `holder.venueImage` and `photoUrl`?

Comment: venueImage is the imageview in which i want to load the image and photourl is the string url of the image

Comment: @iturki The thing is if i have an array of string urls, can i load them in the imageview  one after the other with fade-in fade-out animation?